# How to connect to DSL modem using PPPoE?

Tags: 10.10, networking, pppoe, dsl

I am connecting to the internet through a pppoe connection, but for some reason I can not connect to my modem (it's address is 192.168.1.1).

Before I set my pppoe connection, I could connect.

So, is there a way?

EDIT

The output of ifconfig is :

```
r@PlaviZec:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:d4:f7:02:d4  
          inet6 addr: fe80::213:d4ff:fef7:2d4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2811 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2801 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2538831 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:448591 (448.5 KB)
          Interrupt:21 Base address:0xa000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1600 (1.6 KB)  TX bytes:1600 (1.6 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:92.229.42.177  P-t-P:213.191.64.59  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
          RX packets:2794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:2476277 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:381240 (381.2 KB)
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: Did you set up the modem as a modem, or as a modem/router? I'd advise resetting the modem back to defaults and configuring again.

Comment: @Jonathon Where do I do that setup? By resetting the model back to default, do you mean pressing the button to get it to factory settings?

Comment: I had to submit an answer to add an image. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up your device as a plain modem removes its ability to provide network addresses to your network, instead it acts only as a modem, passing the internet connection directly to your PC.

[image: Device mode setting]

Looking at your ifconfig:

> ppp0
>   inet addr:92.229.x.x P-t-P:213.191.x.x Mask:255.255.255.255

you can see your internet (external) IP address, and here

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet
>            inet6 addr: fe80::x:x:x:x/64 Scope:Link

you can see you don't have an internal IP address. Hence you will not be able to connect to any other devices in your network.

In your modem/router settings you should have the option to set it up as a router so it gives out IP addresses and shares the internet connection between devices. This setup depends on your router, though.

To reset to factory settings you normally power up the device while holding in the reset button for 30 seconds or so.